# NodeJS : Loop through nested JSON and remove elements based on a condition

Tags: node.js, json, recursion, nested, iteration

Let's say I have a below object:

```
{
"schema": [
{
  "field": "name",
  "type": "String",
  "enabled": true
},
{
  "field": "age",
  "type": "Int",
  "enabled": false
},
{
  "field": "modelObj",
  "type": "object",
  "enabled": true,
  "stuff": [
    {
      "name": "mod1",
      "type": "array",
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "name": "mod2",
      "type": "String",
      "enabled": false
    },
    {
     "name": "mod3",
      "type": "array",
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "modelArr",
  "type": "array",
  "enabled": false,
  "elements": {
    "elementsType": "String"
  }
},
{
  "name": "modelsNestedArr",
  "type": "array",
  "enabled": true,
  "elements": {
    "elementsType": "object"
  },
  "stuff": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "String",
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
      "name": "models",
      "type": "array",
      "enabled": false,
      "elements": {
        "elementsType": "String"
      }
    }
  ]
  }
  ]
  }
```

I want to loop through this object recursively, and based on if "enabled" is  false, remove that item.

So expected Output is:

```
[
{
  "field": "name",
  "type": "String",
  "enabled": true
},
{
  "field": "modelObj",
  "type": "object",
  "enabled": true,
  "stuff": [
    {
      "name": "mod1",
      "type": "array",
      "enabled": true
    },
    {
     "name": "mod3",
      "type": "array",
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "modelsNestedArr",
  "type": "array",
  "enabled": true,
  "elements": {
    "elementsType": "object"
  },
  "stuff": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "String",
      "enabled": true
    }
  ]
  }
 ]
```

I have written the code as below:

```
function r(a){
     for (i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(!a[i].enabled){
         a.splice(i,1)
        } else if (a[i].enabled){
            if(a[i].type == "object"){
              if(a[i]){
                a[i].stuff= r(a[i].stuff)
              }
        } else if (a[i].type == "array"){
            if(a[i].hasOwnProperty("elements") && a[i].elements.elementsType== "object"){
               a[i].stuff= r(a[i].stuff)
           }
        } 
      }
    }

    return a
    }

    var final = r(a.schema)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(final))
```

But with this I get the below output:

Errored Output:

```
[
{
"field": "name",
"type": "String",
"enabled": true
},
{
"field": "age",
"type": "Int",
"enabled": false
},
{
"field": "modelObj",
"type": "object",
"enabled": true,
"stuff": [
  {
    "name": "mod1",
    "type": "array",
    "enabled": true
  },
  {
    "name": "mod2",
    "type": "String",
    "enabled": false
  },
  {
    "name": "mod3",
    "type": "array",
    "enabled": true
  }
]
},
{
"name": "modelArr",
"type": "array",
"enabled": false,
"elements": {
  "elementsType": "String"
}
},
{
"name": "modelsNestedArr",
"type": "array",
"enabled": true,
"elements": {
  "elementsType": "object"
},
"stuff": [
  {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "String",
    "enabled": true
  }
]
}
]
```

WHat exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function using .map() and .filter() will make your life easier:

```
  function isEnabledRecursive(data){
    return data.filter(
      item=>item.enabled
    )
    .map(
      item=>item.stuff?Object.assign(item,{stuff:isEnabledRecursive(item.stuff)})
      :item
    );
  }
const dataWithFilteredSchema = Object.assign(data, {schema:isEnabledRecursive(data.schema)})
```

This will work to any depth.

It does assume that all your arrays are in the `stuff` property. If you had other properties with arrays of objects in them you'd have to cycle through each property with something like `for(property of item)` to see if they had an array in them.

As for why your original code isn't working, nothing in your else if statements are running. When you say `a[i].type` or `a[i].dataType` it is undefined. You probably meant to say `typeof a[i] === "object"` and `typeof a[i] === "array"`

Comment: This helped me a lot. I need to read up on map and filter better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From my observations, either your schema object is inconsistent or the function.
Your schema object has both **type** and **dataType** keys. I'm considering all of it as **type**, and here is the solution.

With your splice implementation, the array was subjected to change amidst the loop and might skip few indices.

E.g. if the array was,

```
[
  {name: 'mod1', enabled: false},
  {name: 'mod2', enabled: true},
  {name: 'mod3', enabled: true}
]
```

After the deletion of index 0, array length becomes 2 instead of 3. Hence, one less element will be accessed.

Hence I included another object **deleteIndices** to mark the indices for deletion after the completion of the loop.

> BTW, you can always choose **map** and **filter** to make this way
>   simpler.

```
function r(a) {
  let deleteIndices = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (!a[i].enabled) {
      deleteIndices[i] = true;
    } else {
      if (a[i].type == "object") {
        a[i].stuff = r(a[i].stuff)
      } else if (a[i].type == "array" && a[i].elements && a[i].elements.elementsType == "object") {
        a[i].stuff = r(a[i].stuff)
      }
    }
  }

  a = a.filter((e, index) => !deleteIndices[index])
  return a;
}

schema = r(schema)
```

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the question

Comment: No problem. I guess the above example was good enough to understand the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Let's name **a** your array (object.schema), then the result can be obtained like this:

```
var result = a.filter(element => element.enabled).map(element => {
  if ((element.dataType == "object" || element.type == "array") && element.stuff && element.stuff.length > 0) {
    element.stuff = element.stuff.filter(st => st.enabled);
  }

  return element;
});
```

Be careful, sometimes you have dataType and sometimes you have types as field name.

You should use **map** and **filter**.
Very simple to write and use.

Docs: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)

Comment: nitpick: in the example `a` is an object not an array.

Comment: ´a´ corresponds to ´object.schema´

Comment: This will work on the data the questioner provided but only to depth of 1. If the items in 'stuff' have their own 'stuff' array in them then they won't be filtered. Not sure if that matters to the questioner.

Comment: The 'stuff' can be to any depth,  nested within itself.

Comment: Also, I have fixed the question regarding 'type' and 'dataType'

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and sweet solution i could think and will work for any depth

```js
function r(arr){
  let filtered =  arr.filter((obj)=>{
    return obj.enabled;
  });
  return filtered.map((obj)=>{
    if(obj.stuff)
      obj.stuff = r(obj.stuff)
    return obj
  })
}
result = r(a.schema)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2))
```